# Issue passing an array to a function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass an array of complex numbers (I've created a class called Complex that just stores a real and imaginay part) into my dft function below and get it to spit out some results.  I've tried numerous variations of x -including x[], x[3], **x* to try to pass the array of data into the dft function, but I keep getting "undefined reference to 'Complex::dft(Complex*, int, int)".

I apologise in advance if I've just done something really stupid and obvious, but I've been staring at this for hours and keep drawing a blank.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

This is my dft function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Complex.h"
#include "ofstream_add.h"
#include <cmath>
const double PI=4*atan(1.0);

Complex dft(Complex x[], int N, int n)
{
    Complex holder;
    Complex sum = Complex(0,0);
    Complex temp;

    for (int k=0; k<N; k++)
    {
        temp = Complex(cos(2.0*PI*k*n/N),-sin(2.0*PI*k*n/N));
        sum = sum + x[k] * temp;
    }
    double conv = N;  //convert integer to double as complex takes in doubles
    Complex complexN((1/conv),(1/conv));
    holder = complexN * sum;

    return holder;
}
```

This is my main programme:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Complex.h"
#include "ofstream_add.h"

int main()
{
    int N = 3;
    Complex holder;
    Complex y[N];
    double re,im,ansRe,ansIm;

    Complex a(2,1.7);
    Complex b(3.5,1.2);
    Complex c(4.2,2.3);
    Complex x[3] = {a, b, c};

    for (int n=0;n<N;n++)
    {
        //does some processing on the array of complex numbers an spits out a  
        //real and imaginary part
        double ansRe = holder.dft(x,N,n).getReal();
        double ansIm = holder.dft(x,N,n).getImag();

        //stores the result in a new complex number
        y[n].setReal(ansRe);
        y[n].setImag(ansIm);
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s unrelated to arrays. Simply remove `holder.` from the front of the `dft` calls – it’s not a member function.

Comment: I take it back, I think we do.

Answer (score 2):

Your `dft` function is not a member of `Complex` class:

```
Complex dft(Complex x[], int N, int n)
{
    ...
}
```

so you shouldn't call it on an `holder` object, i.e. instead of `holder.dft(x,N,n).getReal()` do:

```
double ansRe = dft(x,N,n).getReal();
```

Also consider using `std::vector<Complex>` instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: The calling code is expecting a `Complex` - it calls `getReal` on it.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call the `dft` function as if it was a member in your `Complex` class, but it's a free function. You should call it as a free function:

```
    Complex ans = dft(x,N,n);
    double ansRe = ans.getReal();
    double ansIm = ans.getImag();
```